# Unable to execute delegate transaction on testnet

Tags: web3.js, staking

I'm using the solana/web3.js library and trying to send a delegate transaction but I'm getting:

```
SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0xc
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:7348:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:7309:20)
    at async sendTransaction () {
  logs: [
    'Program Stake11111111111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program Stake11111111111111111111111111111111111111 failed: custom program error: 0xc'
  ]
}
```

Double checked that the voteAccount, validatorAddress etc is actually correct and the same code works just fine on devnet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`custom program error: 0xc` corresponds to `StakeError::InsufficientDelegation`.  On testnet, there is now an enforced 1 SOL minimum delegation, so you'll need more SOL in the account in order to delegate it.  Once the other clusters upgrade to 1.14, the vote will happen again, for devnet and mainnet.

More information about the change at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/22559

Comment: ah, thank you - could you share how did you go from 0xc to StakeError::InsufficientDelegation?

Comment: Of course! `0xc` in hex corresponds to 12 in decimal, so counting from zero, `InsufficientDelegation` is the 12th element at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/2562e1b2965d6a3c211015c98523a200c0e1f83d/sdk/program/src/stake/instruction.rs#L62